# Why does running performance tests in the console give different results

Tags: javascript, benchmarking

I wanted to check the performance of different ways to check if a value is an array. I used console.time and jsperf and got conflicting results. Creating a script and running it gave similar results to jsperf.

jsperf link http://jsperf.com/is-it-an-array

my code

```
a={test:'a',foo:'bar'};
b='abcdef';
c=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
d=3.14

length=1e6;
l=length;
console.time(1);
while(l--){
  a instanceof Array ?true:false;
  b instanceof Array ?true:false;
  c instanceof Array ?true:false;
  d instanceof Array ?true:false;
}
console.timeEnd(1);
l=length;
console.time(2);
while(l--){
  a.pop?true:false;
  b.pop?true:false;
  c.pop?true:false;
  d.pop?true:false;
}
console.timeEnd(2);
l=length;
console.time(3);
while(l--){
  Array.isArray(a)?true:false;
  Array.isArray(b)?true:false;
  Array.isArray(c)?true:false;
  Array.isArray(d)?true:false;
}
console.timeEnd(3);
l=length;
console.time(4);
while(l--){
  a.constructor == Array?true:false;
  b.constructor == Array?true:false;
  c.constructor == Array?true:false;
  d.constructor == Array?true:false;
}
console.timeEnd(4);
```

On my computer Firefox performs much better than Chrome on these tests using jsperf. The fastest solution by far is using `instanceof` and the worst is `.pop`. In chrome `isArray` is fastest and `.pop` is still the slowest.

But running these tests in the console gives different results `.pop` is never slowest.

Firefox

```
1: 153.35ms
2: 166.88ms //.pop
3: 169.94ms
4: 193.73ms
```

Chrome

```
1: 286.000ms
2: 207.000ms //.pop
3: 270.000ms
4: 266.000ms
```

What makes using the console to run the code give different results?

Comment: I'd worry about which method is actually more reliable for determining if something is an array rather than which is fastest.

Comment: Benchmarking with global variables? Not a good idea imo.

Comment: I edited the question hopefully it is clearer. The main question is what makes using the console to run the code give different results?

Comment: i too have noticed a discrepancy with chrome in other perf tests between the page-loaded code and console-run code. i have not found a good explanation, but i know you're not crazy... let's hope a genius can come along and explain it to both of us.

Comment: @MattBurland agreed this is more about why there is a difference.